# Ionic manage multiple white-label apps from one code base

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I support/manage multiple native white-label ios/android applications from one code-base using Ionic Pro?

Specifically, I would like to deploy a new standalone application for each existing client. This will be a white-label solution where the code would be essentially the same between clients. Features will be managed using server side configurations and a client-side compile-time config file. The intention is to create multiple "application instances" (one for each client) on the ionic dashboard AND to have unique ios/android certs for each application.

I have a couple of thoughts on creating a compile-time script that will update the config.xml and package.json files based on a passed in flag when I push my changes to Ionic Pro's git management system. I will then build the binaries using Ionic Pro's online dashboard.

I am still working through other details with this system and would like to know what other approaches people have used/are out there.

Comment: Could you share more on what you ended up doing?